# How to test file system filter drivers on Windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems, filter-driver

Given that unloading a file system filter driver requires a reboot, what is the best way to test one?

Is there a better/less painful way than rebooting a VM every single time?

Comment: Does it require a reboot?  It is a little below the area of the code I work on, but we have a file system filter driver developed as a minifilter which can be loaded and unloaded on demand.

Comment: @Luke: I just started working on a sample file system filter driver (*not* a minifilter -- perhaps I should try a minifilter instead?), and when I installed the driver, `sc` told me that the driver is indeed `STOPPABLE`, but when I tried to stop it, it told me that's not possible, so I had to reboot. I guess I might've done something wrong?

Comment: I don't really know the implementation details other than that it is a minifilter.

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful: [File System Filter Driver Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial)

> **Set driver unload routine**
>
> The last part of the driver initialization sets an unload routine.
>   Setting the driver unload routine makes the driver unloadable, and you
>   can load/unload it multiple times without system restart. However,
>   this driver is made unloadable only for debugging purpose, because
>   file system filters can’t be unloaded safely. **Never do this in
>   production code**.